# Dependencies with autocomplete in Drupal 8

Tags: autocomplete, drupal-8

I try to implement a autocomplete field in my search. After declare all dependencies, the console page insist to show that my function autocomplete does not exist:

See

PHP

```
$form['basic']['keys'] = array(
  '#type' => 'search',
  '#title' => $this->t('Digite sua pesquisa'),
  '#default_value' => $keys,
  '#size' => 30,
  '#maxlength' => 255,
);

$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'busca/busca_form';
$form['basic']['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Search'),
```

my js

$( document ).ready(function() {

```
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
];


$("#edit-keys" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

});

and my library

```
busca_form:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/complete.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/jquery.ui.autocomplete
```

Error: complete.js?v=8.1.2:35 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function(…)

Any Idea? Tks

Comment: Instead of doing all of this complicated mess, just use HTML's `datalist`.

Comment: Hi Eli Sadoff, good suggestion, but this tags are just examples ... My system get thousands of then

Answer (score 1):

This way it's working fine here.

```drupal
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings, doc) {
    "use strict";

    Drupal.behaviors.Myautocomplete = {
        attach: function myFunc(context, settings) {
     

        
                var options = ["Java", "Jaca"];
                jQuery("#lookfor").autocomplete({
                source: options
                });
            
        
        
        },
    };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings, document);
```